# Why is .replace() not working on Input field=number

Tags: html, jquery

I am having a form and one item is the price. I am using the input field type number:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" lang="en" value="0.01" id="productPrice" name="productPrice" class="form-control">
```

My problem is, that my database is expecting a period in the number instead of a comma (e.g. 1.23), but I am located in Europe and we are using "," (e.g. 10,99€). So I want to add a jquery function to replace , to . on the fly. I tried different ways, but it is never working it always clears the whole value and it is just empty. If I use the input type text it is working without an issue.
This one is working for type text:

```
$('input#productPrice').on('input', function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, "."); 
});
```

I am very confused now

Thanks!
Jan

Comment: *"my database is expecting a period in the number"* - It sounds like the actual issue is further downstream than what's shown here.  The culture format is just for display, it doesn't have anything to do with the underlying numeric value.  Are you storing this in your database as a string instead of a number?  Where in the end-to-end process is this actually failing and how are you handling the value there?

Comment: If you do `console.log(this.value)` before the replace, what do you see?

Comment: The result is empty

Comment: @David, no I am using float in my MySQL database and the DB expects X.XX and not X,XX.

Comment: @Sylber: The *stored value* doesn't have any formatting.  You're operating on a false assumption.  What you have here is an XY Problem.  What actual problem occurs when you try to save the value in the database?

Comment: No problem with the database, I just want to replace the , with an . on the client side on the fly

Comment: @Sylber: *"My problem is, that my database is expecting a period in the number instead of a comma [...] No problem with the database"* - You're providing conflicting information.  Please update the question to clarify the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: *console.log(this.value) before the replace* .. *The result is empty* .. do you think this might be the problem area?

Answer (score -1):

The issue arises because the input type="number" behaves differently than input type="text". As browser has a validation technique for number input.
you can try this approach:

```
$('input#productPrice').on('input', function() {

  var currentValue = this.value;

  var replacedValue = currentValue.replace(/,/g, ".");

  setTimeout(function() {
    this.value = replacedValue;
  }, 10);
});
```

this 10 ms delay is to avoid browser validation conflict. you can skip the timeout section, if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your message, unfortunately it is not working. With the timeout nothing happenes at all and without the timeout the old issue reappears: everything gets deleted after putting in a ","

Comment: Well then another approach i can say is that, you can use text input and than custom validation for min and max values.